# Using a FOR loop to compare items in a list with items in an ARRAY

Tags: bash, shell, file, scripting

Without too much fluff, basically I'm creating an array of IP addresses from a user provided file. Then I have another file with three columns of data and multiple lines, the first column is  IP addresses.

What I'm trying to do is loop through the file with 3 columns of data and compare the IP addresses with the values in the arrary, and if a value is present from file in the array, to then print some text as well as the 3rd column from that line of the file.

I have a feeling I'm taking a really wrong approach and making things a lot harder than what they need to be!

Semi-Pseudo code below

```
#!/bin/bash 

scopeFile=$1 
data=$2

scopeArray=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
scopeArray+=("$line")
done <$1

for line in $2; do 
  if [[ $line == scopeArray ]]; then 

  awk '{print $3 " is in scope!"}' $2; 

  else 

    echo "$line is NOT in scope!" 

  fi;
done
```

---

EDIT: Added example files for visulisation for context, data.txt 
file is dynamically generated elsewhere but the format is always the same.

```
scope.txt=$1
```

```
192.168.0.14
192.168.0.15
192.168.0.16
```

```
data.txt=$2
```

```
192.168.0.14 : example.com
192.168.0.15 : foobar.com
192.168.0.19 : test.com
```

Comment: Why don't you do all that in awk instead? It'd be way easier than this.

Comment: @oguz.ismail I know awk is pretty powerful but do you think it would be able to do everything I've mentioned? 

Do you have an example of how you'd do it? TIA

Comment: Yes, I think it would be. You need to [edit] your question to add sample input & output though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing what you wanted.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -t scopeArray < "$1"

while read -r col1 col2 col3; do
  for item in "${!scopeArray[@]}"; do
    if [[ $col1 == "${scopeArray[item]}" ]]; then
      printf '%s is in scope!\n' "$col3"
      unset 'scopeArray[item]' && break
    else
      printf '%s is not is scope!\n' "$col1" >&2
    fi
  done 
done < "$2"
```

- The shell is not the best if not the right tool for comparing files, but it will get you there slowly but surely.
- `mapfile` is a bash4+ feature jyfi.

Comment: I've added a comment to my previous code block, its in the code block because SO didn't like the formatting of how I'd laid out how my data.txt is supposed to look. Your solution looks like it should work though. I'll give it a shot shortly. Thank you!

Comment: Your solution was pretty much a hole in one! Changed about some styling bits and deleted the else section as I didn't anticipate how much output there would be with my actual files. Thank you very much though! :-)